# Gitlab CI not activated although .gitlab-ci.yml exists

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I recently created a new gitlab project which hosts a dockerfile. I want to use Gitlab CI/CD to build the dockerfile.
While I already used CI/CD in another project this one won't work.
Although the .yml file is present, gitlab shows the "Set up CI" link in the overview, the pipelines window shows nothing but the "get started with pipelines" link and the jobs window says "No jobs to show".

**My .gitlab-ci.yml file:**

```
image: docker:stable

variables:
   # When using dind service we need to instruct docker, to talk with the
   # daemon started idnside of the service. The daemon is available with
   # a network connection instead of the default /var/run/docker.sock socket.
   #
   # The 'docker' hostname is the alias of the service container as described at
   # https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#accessing-the-services
   #
   # Note that if you're using Kubernetes executor, the variable should be set to
   # tcp://localhost:2375 becausde of how Kubernetes executor connects services
   # to the job container
   DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
   # When using dind, it's wise to use the overlayfs driver for
   # improved performance.
   DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

services:
   - docker:dind

before_script:
   - docker info

build_job:
    stage: build
    script:
     - docker build -t Laravel-Ci-Docker-Image .
    tags:
     - dockerbuilder
```

**My runner for this project:**

- Active: yes
- Protected: no
- Can run untagged jobs: yes
- Locked to this project: Yes
- Tags: dockerbuilder
- Name: gitlab-runner
- Version: 11.0.0
- Revision: 5396d320
- Platform: linux
- Architecture: amd64
- Description: Docker Builder
- Last contact: 24 minutes ago

The "pipelines" option is checked in the permissions section.
Did I miss something? What are the possible reasons for gitlab not recognizing the .gitlab-ci.yml file?

**Update / more details**
Opening the .yml file it says "This GitLab CI configuration is valid."
It's a self hosted Gitlab instance.

Comment: On gitlab interface they told you if gitlab-ci file is present, and entering on it told if the syntax are correct. Did you verify this?

Comment: Is this with the cloud hosted Gitlab? Sometimes, I just have to wait until the next day to see my .gitlab-ci.yml picked up.

Comment: @SakuraKinomoto I added some more context. The file should be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was a gitlab-runner problem then the CI would be on the `pending` status but would create a pipeline for that. What I see in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` is lack of

```
stages:
  - build
```

Because you defined it in your job but didn't create the definition of this stage

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem are on the runner.

On your question you're talking about a runner with last contact 24 minutes ago.
Check if the runner has goes away or comp is shutdown, because, a runner working OK check the server for jobs to run very often.

If the runner comp are working, check runner service status. You can do it with "gitlab-runner status" and "gitlab-runner list". If all is OK, the runner you're talking about should be on the list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Please explain, what you mean with "runner **comp**".

Comment: Are talking about the computer or phisical server. If the computer are working...

Comment: Oh okay. The server is running, gitlab-runner status is ok and the runner is visible in the list. Well everything should be OK. But the situation is still the same.